# Unable to understand following function declaration

Tags: c, linux, function, linux-device-driver, gcc-extensions

Can anybody explain following function declaration.

```
inline uint64_t MY_FUNC(unsigned long param) __attribute__ ((pure, always_inline));
```

Comment: Tape in console: man gcc ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`always_inline` and `pure` are `gcc` function attributes. From gcc [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> always_inline
>
> Generally, functions are not inlined unless optimization is specified. For functions declared inline, this attribute inlines the function independent of any restrictions that otherwise apply to inlining. Failure to inline such a function is diagnosed as an error. Note that if such a function is called indirectly the compiler may or may not inline it depending on optimization level and a failure to inline an indirect call may or may not be diagnosed.

Your `MY_FUNC` function already has the `inline` function specifier but in C `inline` is only a suggestion to inline and the compiler has no obligation to inline the function.

> pure
>
> Many functions have no effects except the return value and their return value depends only on the parameters and/or global variables. Such a function can be subject to common subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an arithmetic operator would be. These functions should be declared with the attribute pure.

Answer (score 0):

```
inline uint64_t MY_FUNC(unsigned long param) __attribute__ ((pure, always_inline));
```

- `inline` -- function declared inline, either as optimization hint or for linking purposes.
- `uint64_t` -- fixed-width return type. Refer to `<stdint.h>`.
- `MY_FUNC` -- function name
- `unsigned long` -- type of parameter
- `param` -- name of parameter
- `__attribute__ ((pure, always_inline))` -- GCC compiler-specific attributes. See ouah who ninja'd their description.

Voting to close as "too broad".